# How to add fragment to activity MaterialContainerTransform / sharedElementTransition?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation, android-transitions, shared-element-transition

This is how my fragment to fragment transition looks like
Here's the code:

```
 //Launch Fragment
 override fun onClick(v: View?) {
    when (v) {
        main_sort -> {
            val extras = FragmentNavigatorExtras(main_sort to "fragment2")
            findNavController().navigate(
                R.id.action_dashboardFragment_to_barsFragment,
                null,
                null,
                extras
            )
        }
    }

 //Target Fragment
 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    sharedElementEnterTransition = MaterialContainerTransform().apply {
        fadeMode = MaterialContainerTransform.FADE_MODE_CROSS
        duration = 500
    }
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
}
```

[image: Fragment to Fragment]

For some reason, I had to switch to activity
this is how my fragment to activity transition is looking

```
 //launch fragment
override fun onClick(v: View?) {
    when (v) {
        main_sort -> {
            val options =
                ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(requireActivity(), main_sort, "fragment2")
            val intent = Intent(requireContext(), SortingActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent,options.toBundle())
        }
    }
}

//target activity
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_bars)
    val bounds = ChangeBounds()
    bounds.duration = 500
    window.sharedElementEnterTransition = bounds
```

[image: fragment to Activity transtion]

as you can see the animation from fragment to activity is weird and doesn't feel as good as the fragment to fragment one, also the exit animation is flickery, and the activity just suddenly changes into image not as smooth as it should be.  How can I achieve that fragment to fragment transition in fragment to activity...